# Is there a way to mock earlier versions of Firefox?

Tags: linux, firefox, firefox-extensions, compatibility, centos-6

I'd like to develop a website that is compatible with firefox 10, but I'd rather use a more up to date browser (firefox 30+).

Is there a way to view web pages as though you're using an older browser (for instance, how CSS is rendered differently), but still have compatibility with uptodate addons?

Note: I'm not asking about Version Strings, like in this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/624042/113848)

Double Note: This needs to be available offline - webapp solutions won't work.

Note Tres: I'm on Centos 6.3

Comment: possible duplicate of (or at least helpful) [Is there a plugin that lets you switch firefox versions](http://superuser.com/questions/624020/is-there-a-plugin-that-lets-you-switch-firefox-versions)

Comment: http://www.browserstack.com/ has firefox 10 available for Windows 7 (32-bit and 64-bit)

Comment: http://browsershots.org/ has firefox 10 and it is free.

Comment: See http://mashable.com/2014/02/26/browser-testing-tools/ for more options

Comment: @DavidPostill those all require you to be online. I need an offline solution unfortunately.

Comment: [Installing and running multiple versions of Firefox.](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2249039) -- [Mozilla Firefox, Portable Ed.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Ed./) has versions going back to 2.0.0.8

Comment: @DavidPostill Those are `.exe`s and I'm on centos 6.3

Comment: On linux, you can grab the .tar.bz version, set up a new profile, and run different versions side by side. http://superuser.com/a/878800/10165 worked for me . If you want FF 10, and *know* it works, this is what you probably need to do.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek sounds like a good answer.

Comment: I'll post a full answer when I get home - http://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/10.0/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-10.0.tar.bz2 has a copy of FF, but I don't know if the command line options I used would still work

Answer (score 1):

You don't - by the time you get a newer brower to exhibit all the quirks of an old one, you're running an old browser anyway.

While I haven't gotten it to run side by side with a new profile as , [as I can with the newer versions of firefox](https://superuser.com/a/878800/10165), you can probably grab a [tar.bz install of firefox from mozilla](http://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/10.0/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-10.0.tar.bz2), unpack it, and run it using the *full path* to the firefox 10 binary (since otherwise you'll run the regular firefox binary in path)

I suspect the command line options for profile generation and using a different profile are different, but even without that, your best bet is to run ff10